# Quoting hell with formulas

Tags: r

I have a task I need to perform repeatedly, so I am attempting to write a function for it.  My function is nearly complete, except for one defect:  I cannot pass a formula as an argument unless it is in the form of a string.

```
library(lme4)
library(lazyeval)

get_pvals_qrhs <- function(df, cols, qrhs) {
    cols <- substitute(cols)
    col_pos <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(df)), names(df))
    pos <- eval(cols, col_pos)
    formulas <- lapply(pos, function(x) formula(paste(colnames(df[x]), "~", qrhs)))
    models <- lapply(formulas, lmer, data=df, REML=FALSE)
    tvals <- lapply(models, function(x) data.frame(coef(summary(x)))[c(2), ]$t.value)
    pvals <- lapply(tvals, function(x) { 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(x))) })
    return(unlist(pvals))
}

works <- get_pvals_qrhs(iris, Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width, "Species + (1 + Petal.Length | Petal.Width)")
works

get_pvals_rhs <- function(df, cols, rhs) {
    cols <- substitute(cols)
    col_pos <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(df)), names(df))
    pos <- eval(cols, col_pos)
    formulas <- lapply(pos, function(x) formula(paste(colnames(df[x]), "~", quote(rhs))))
    models <- lapply(formulas, function(x) lmer, data=df, REML=FALSE)
    tvals <- lapply(models, function(x) data.frame(coef(summary(x)))[c(2), ]$t.value)
    pvals <- lapply(tvals, function(x) { 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(x))) })
    return(unlist(pvals))
}

fails <- get_pvals_rhs(iris, Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width, Species + (1 + Petal.Length | Petal.Width))
fails
```

No matter what I do to the `rhs` term in the `formulas <- ...` line in the second function, I cannot get the results that I get from the first function.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to substitute to get the expression, and then you can deparse that to turn that into a string

```
get_pvals_rhs <- function(df, cols, rhs) {
  cols <- substitute(cols)
  rhs <- deparse(substitute(rhs))
  col_pos <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(df)), names(df))
  pos <- eval(cols, col_pos)
  formulas <- lapply(pos, function(x) formula(paste(colnames(df[x]), "~", rhs)))
  models <- lapply(formulas, lmer, data=df, REML=FALSE)
  tvals <- lapply(models, function(x) data.frame(coef(summary(x)))[c(2), ]$t.value)
  pvals <- lapply(tvals, function(x) { 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(x))) })
  return(unlist(pvals))
}
```

And tested with

```
get_pvals_rhs(iris, Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width, Species + (1 + Petal.Length | Petal.Width))
```

But really, when working with formula parts, its usually better to always prefix them with `~` so you don't have to `substitute()` and you can use functions like `update()` to more easily change formulas. Something more like

```
get_pvals_rhs <- function(df, cols, rhs) {
  cols <- substitute(cols)
  col_pos <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(df)), names(df))
  pos <- eval(cols, col_pos)
  formulas <- lapply(colnames(df[pos]), function(x) update(rhs, reformulate(".", x)))
  models <- lapply(formulas, lmer, data=df, REML=FALSE)
  tvals <- lapply(models, function(x) data.frame(coef(summary(x)))[c(2), ]$t.value)
  pvals <- lapply(tvals, function(x) { 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(x))) })
  return(unlist(pvals))
}
get_pvals_rhs(iris, Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width, ~ Species + (1 + Petal.Length | Petal.Width))
```

Comment: Sigh, edit fail. I tested both your suggestions, and neither worked over here.  The first returned:
`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  unused arguments (data = list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, ` followed by more numbers.  The second returned the same thing. :-(

Comment: @JackTwilley  Did you copy exactly what I put? You had a typo/error in your lapply with lmer as well.

Comment: I thought that I had copied exactly what you put.  Was using `function(x)` in front of `lmer` the typo you mentioned?

Comment: Yes. That’s was preventing the padding of the data parameter to lmer which would give the unused arguments error.

Comment: I now wonder how many of those permutations of `deparse`, `substitute` and friends I had tried with that `function(x)` in the way.  Argh.  Thank you!